# url redirect not working in netlify for certain rules

Tags: next.js, netlify

I tried with the below redirecting the first two works and the last one is not working. Not sure whether I'm doing it correctly

Redirection working:

```
 /forums  https://test/forums  200 
 /forums/*  https://test/forums/:splat  200
```

Redirection Not working

```
/pushed/*/p7.min.css https://test/:splat/p7.min.css 200
```

The url looks like this. The reason I'm trying with the * in the middle is the number after the res path will change always. So I need a url rewrite which works each time since we dont know the random number

```
https://test1/pushed/res/638314797085341666/p7/p7.min.css
https://test2/pushed/res/638320800675496601/p7/p7.min.css
```

Answer (score 0):

I work for Netlify Support.

In the future please ask questions in our helpdesk (https://www.netlify.com/support) or forums (https://answers.netlify.com), rather than on stackoverflow since we don't monitor that nor the-service-formerly-known-as-twitter, but I happened to notice your tweet today.

@ooxvyd is correct in that the `*` character is the problem, but not for the reason they said.  Our redirects insist that the `*` match only "the rest of the URL", and cannot be used as shorthand for `this portion of the URL such as what is between two slashes`, but what you are looking for, for the latter is instead placeholders:  https://docs.netlify.com/routing/redirects/redirect-options/#placeholders

Note that these too are not incredibly flexible - `/dir1/:placeholder/dir2` will only match `/dir1/something/dir2` not `/dir1/something/somethingelse/dir2` (the slashes are the delimiter here), but hopefully that is sufficient for your use case.

If you need the latter, you'll be limited to making broader redirects like `/pushed/*` and sending that to a page or function where your logic (on a page: client-side JS;  in a function, code you write as a lambda) parses out the URL and responds more appropriately based on the context.

Our next-runtime adapter, for instance, allows you to specify redirects using full regexps in `next.config.js`:  https://docs.netlify.com/integrations/frameworks/next-js/redirects-and-rewrites/#when-to-use-next-js-redirects-or-rewrites - but it essentially implements the pattern I mentioned:

- all possible paths covered by the redirect
- are forwarded to a lambda function
- that parses the path and returns the relevant data

There is a third path as well, which is edge functions, which you can specify more granularly, and let our integration with Deno do the similar mapping work for you:  https://edge-functions-examples.netlify.app/example/rewrite is one sample.

Note that I will be unlikely to see responses to this post, so if you have followup questions, I suggest you ask in our forums at https://answers.netlify.com

Good luck!